# foreach line and add something else

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin

hello i have something with this code bellow

```
$text =  nl2br($_POST['inputtext']);
foreach(explode("<br />",$text) as $ok){
echo "944".$OK."<BR />";
}
```

what i have tried is
when i enter something in the text area and i click change look the result

```
944test
944 test
```

anyway way the first result is good but the second one i get space between the number and the word i do not no why is that happen i tried it before and i did not get anything like that

Comment: `$ok` is not the same as `$OK`

Comment: the text is probaby `\r\n`, and nl2br doesn't deal with `\r` chars, which'll simply be see as a space.

Comment: i just did a mistake when i was writting the question anyway the code works perfctly the problem only in the space what i habe to do?
first line there is no space but after that there is spaces

Comment: Take a look at `trim` and `htmlspecialchars` in the php manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nl2br` does *not* replace newline characters with `<br />`, it simply inserts them *before* newline characters. The existing newline characters may be causing you problems. You may have to write your own function. Something like:

```
function nl2br2($string) {
  return str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), "<br />", $string);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just trim space off the resulting array as well.

```
foreach (array_map('trim', explode('<br />', nl2br2($text))) as $ok) {
  echo "944". $ok ."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly could be that it is looking through your text and say you have:

```
test \n
test
```

You then explode the words and you will get

```
"test<br />"
" test<br/>"
```

This is because of the space that you are not removing between the first word and the enter key or \n. Use the following and it should work fine for you:

```
foreach (explode("<br />", $text) as $ok) {
    echo "944" . ltrim($ok) . "<BR />";
}
```